# Transforms in cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: integral-transforms, cyclic-groups

Are there any elementary examples of [transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform#Table_of_transforms) whose "time-domain" is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do Fourier analysis on any locally compact abelian group. For instance, a [Gauss sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) is one example of a Fourier transform on $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. You could replace the Dirichlet character by any function.